# solve statistical problem, which includes the arithmetic mean and variance

Tags: statistics, average, means

### **The mean and variance of the times
$$ x_1, x_2, ..., x_N$$
used in performing N similar tasks, are: 14 and 2.89.
The cost to perform each task is   $$y_i = 20 + 0.5x_i + 0.1x_i^2 $$
Find the mean of the costs**

**I am clear about this,
$$a)\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i}}{N}=14$$
$$b)\sigma ^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{(x_i- \bar{x}) ^2}}{N}=2.89$$
but I do not know how to enter $$y_i$$ there**

***edited what is in bold***

Comment: I don't understand your post. What is given, what is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: I would recommend rewriting the problem statement. What does "perform the mean and variance of the times (...) " mean ?  I understand that some means and variances are at play, but the wording is not understandable.

Comment: Edited,I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Please use periods for decimal points.  Here it looks like a list of three items for $y_i$

Comment: @Ross Millikan,    thanks for the indication , corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the formula for $\overline y$ the same way you have for $\overline x$.  Plug in the expression you have for $y_i$ to get the sum in terms of $x_i$.  After some manipulation you should be able to write it in terms of $\overline x$ and $\overline{x^2}$ and finally in terms of $\overline x$ and $\sigma^2$

$\sigma_x ^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{(x_i- \bar{x}) ^2}}{N}=
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{(x_i^2- 2\bar{x}x_i+\bar x^2) }}{N}=
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{(x_i^2- \bar x^2) }}{N}=\bar {x^2}-(\bar x)^2$
You know $\sigma_x^2$ and $(\bar x)^2$, so now you know $\bar{x^2}$ to use in the computation of $\bar y$

Comment: It is precisely that part that I do not understand, (algebraic manipulation) if you could direct me a little I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: even if $\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i}}{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{}20+0.5x_i+ 0.1x_i^2}{N}=20+ 7 + 0.1\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i^2}}{N} =14$

Comment: $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i^2}}{N} =-130$

Comment: You should not have the second equals sign in the next to last comment because the third expression is $\overline y$.  The next equals sign is  correct and what is intended.  It is not equal to $14$, so there is no problem there.  Now expand the definition of $\sigma^2$ to get terms in $\overline {x^2}$ and $(\overline x)^2$.  You know the second is $196$, so using the given $\sigma^2$ you can get $\overline{x^2}$

Comment: I think what you are saying is this: 
$\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i}}{N}$,
$\bar{y}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{y_i}}{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{  20 + 0.5x_i + 0.1x_i^2 }}{N}= 20 +7+0.1\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i ^2}}{N} =27+0.1\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i ^2}}{N} => \bar{y}=27+0.1\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i ^2}}{N}$

Comment: $\sigma_x ^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{(x_i- \bar{x}) ^2}}{N}$,
$\sigma_y ^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{(y_i- \bar{y}) ^2}}{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{(y_i-  27 - 0.1\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i ^2}}{N}) ^2}}{N}$, it is right?I can't think of any more,

Comment: $\sigma_x^2=\frac{\Sigma(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{N} = \frac{\Sigma(x_i^2-2x_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2}{N}$. Can you proceed from here to conclude that $\sigma_x^2 = \frac{\Sigma x_i^2}{N} - \bar{x}^2$?

Comment: thanks to both I reached the final result of 49,931, can you tell me if it is correct